# How to pass proxy to yolov8 in python

Tags: python, yolov8

following is my code for prediction using yolov8. I want to my image urls to be downloaded using proxy.

````
from ultralytics import YOLO

proxy_dict = {
    "http": "http://proxy_address:port",
}

# Load a pretrained YOLOv8n model
model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')

# Define remote image or video URL
source = 'https://ultralytics.com/images/bus.jpg'

# Run inference on the source
results = model(source)  # list of Results objects```
````

Answer (score 0):

you can always set proxy to environment variables.

on Linux open terminal and write these commands:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy.server:port
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy.server:port
```

on Windows open CMD and write these commands:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy.server:port
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy.server:port
```

use your proxy instead of `http://username:password@proxy.server:port`